# Asp.net mvc json

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-ajax, jquery

I am working on a mvc project, and having problem with json.

i have created a demo project with list of colors

```
    public JsonResult GetResult()
    {
        List<string> strList = new List<string>();
        strList.Add("white");
        strList.Add("blue");
        strList.Add("black");
        strList.Add("red");
        strList.Add("orange");
        strList.Add("green");
        return this.Json(strList);
    }
```

i am able to get these on my page, but when i try to delete one color, that is when i send the following using jquery

```
function deleteItem(item) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/Delete/white",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: ajaxCallSucceed,
            dataType: "json",
            failure: ajaxCallFailed
        });
    }
```

the controler action

`public JsonResult Delete(string Color) {}`

Color always returns null, even if i have specified "/Home/Delete/white" in the url.

i know i am doing something wrong or missing something, but not able to find out what.

please can any one guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a common public opinion: It's very strange to Pascal-case method parameters as you do...

### The simplest solution to your problem

Renaming your controller action parameter to `id` would do the trick just fine (in case your default route is defined as `{controller}/{action}/{id}`).

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Delete(string id)
{
    // do what's required
}
```

### Don't forget about attributes

And **don't forget** to put the attribute on your action method, otherwise a web crawler would be able to delete all your colour entries.

Either use `HttpPost` or even better `HttpDelete`, because you do use Ajax request anyway, so you can issue a DELETE request.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your url to:

`"/Home/Delete?Color=white"`

The reason is that there isn't a route set up to handle a string called color, like you have.

Have a look at this for info on how to create a custom route that will handle your current url format.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-routes-cs

Answer (score 0):

Check your routes. (Usually set in /global.asax.)

Comment: routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });

Comment: That'll only work if your parameter is named `id`. You need either create a new route that reflects your method or change your method to reflect the current routes.

Answer (score 0):

try this above the default

```
routes.MapRoute("Color", "{controller}/{action}/{color}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", Color = "" });
```

Comment: Try changing {color} to {Color}.